# need some explanation of this code in javascript node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

splitting a string that contains e.g. 5 5 with below code but I am not able to understand what does n will contain after this.

```
let [,n] = parsedInput[0].split(' ');
n = +n + 2;
```

Comment: `parsedInput[0].split(' ');` returns array, `let [,n]` takes the second value of array (i.e at index 1) and assign it to `n`, `+n` is similar to `parseInt(n)`

Comment: thanks a lot for an explanation as I am new to javascript I got really confused with +n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// parsedInput is an array, we are getting the first element of it
// and split it considering the character space as the delimiter
// NOTE: we suppose that parsedInput[0] is a string
parsedInput[0].split(' ');
```

---

```
// The following syntax is called destructuring
let [,n]

//

// It's the equivalent of
const ret = parsedInput[0].split(' ');
let n = ret[1];
```

---

```
// The comma here means that we wants to ignore the first value, and only
// create a variable for the second one
let [,n]

// so obviously the goal here is to extract a word from a str
// example : str => 'word1 word2 word3'
// n will worth 'word2'
```

---

```js
const parsedInput = [
  'word1 word2 word3',
];

let [, n] = parsedInput[0].split(' ');

console.log(n);
```

---

```
// Then this line, is converting n to a number. So we suppose what we are
// looking for in the string is a number
// and then we add 2 to it
n = +n + 2;

// It's equivalent to
const number = Number(n) + 2;
```

```js
const parsedInput = [
  'word1 2 word3',
];

let [, n] = parsedInput[0].split(' ');

n = +n + 2;

console.log(n);
```